# How to add Markers on Map from geoJson with many points (Leaflet)

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm trying to add some markers on my map using a geoJson with Points, I'm following the leaflet [documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html) but it still saying:

> Error: Invalid GeoJSON object.
>   throw new Error('Invalid GeoJSON object.');

My GeoJson:

```
var meta1nJson={
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -38.3613558,
          -8.8044875
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "Ordem": "193",
        "Eixo": "Leste",
        "Meta": "1L",
        "Municipio": "Petrolândia",
        "Estado": "PE",
        "Nome da Comunidade": "Agrovila 4"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -38.3445892,
          -8.7940031
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "Ordem": "194",
        "Eixo": "Leste",
        "Meta": "1L",
        "Municipio": "Petrolândia / Floresta",
        "Estado": "PE",
        "Nome da Comunidade": "Agrovila 5"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -37.8521847,
          -8.6774657
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "Ordem": "195",
        "Eixo": "Leste",
        "Meta": "1L",
        "Municipio": "InajÃ¡/Ibimirim",
        "Estado": "PE",
        "Nome da Comunidade": "Indígena KambiwÃ¡ - Baxa da Alexandra"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -37.9229577,
          -8.645232
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "Ordem": "196",
        "Eixo": "Leste",
        "Meta": "1L",
        "Municipio": "InajÃ¡",
        "Estado": "PE",
        "Nome da Comunidade": "Indígena KambiwÃ¡ -  BarracÃ£o"
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

and how do I try to render markers:

```
var layerComunidades1N = L.geoJson(meta1nJson).addTo(map);
```

I cannot find what I'm doing wrong, according to leaflet documentation if I don't pass the option pointToLayer it is supposed to render default markers, am I wrong?

Comment: check your variable names?

Comment: You were right, but it was just a writing mistake, the problem persists

Comment: Converting your [JavaScript to JSON](http://jsfiddle.net/9WgqN/) and then testing it on [GeoJSONLint](http://geojsonlint.com/) works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any problem with your geojson.  I copied your geojson into [geojson.io](http://geojson.io/) and it [works fine](http://bl.ocks.org/d/3be45826d7b8422a853a).

It does look like you're calling `GeoJSON` incorrectly (your example above shows a call to `geoJson`), however that doesn't explain the error you're getting...

Regardless, [here is a working jsfiddle that visualizes your geojson as markers on a leaflet map](http://jsfiddle.net/hqLKS/2/).

And here is the relevant code (with a base layer for good measure):

```
var map = L.map('map', {
    center: [-9, -38],
    zoom: 7
});

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {       
    id: 'examples.map-20v6611k'
}).addTo(map);

new L.GeoJSON(meta1nJson).addTo(map);
```

Hopefully, that helps.

Comment: First, thanks to waste your time trying to help me. I made some errors on my post, first of all I didn't paste the full code of my geojson cause I thought it was too much code and decided to simplify it, but doing that I ommited exactly where the error was. Following your hint and @ComFreek I was abble to detect where the error was and fix it. Thanks and Sorry about that

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

/* Instantiate an icon. You can have multiple icons also*/

```
var ComunidadeIcon = L.icon({
  iconUrl: 'http://iambrony.dget.cc/mlp/gif/angel_stand_right.gif',
  iconSize: [32, 37],
  iconAnchor: [16, 37],
  popupAnchor: [0, -28]
});
```

/* List objects features from FeatureCollection from GJson*/

```
var layerComunidades1N = L.geoJson(meta1nJson, {
  pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
    return L.marker(latlng, {icon: ComunidadeIcon});
  }, onEachFeature: onEachFeature
}).addTo(map);
```

/* This function can hold many things. I'm using to show a popup*/

```
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
  var popupContent = "<p>DaTerra Web</p>";
  if (feature.properties && feature.properties.popupContent) {
    popupContent += feature.properties.popupContent;
  }
  layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
}
```